# Linear Programming Excel Solver

Tags: excel, linear-programming

I am trying to minimize the objective function in B19. Why the solver can't find any feasible solution? I can't understand. Basically the model is:

Variable: 

- xi

Constraints: 

- xi is boolean

- `sum(li * xi') < F`

- `li * xi > F'` , foreach i

Objective function:

- `sum(xi * di)`

Comment: xi is boolean? In Excel that would mean that it has two possible values, 0 and -1.

Comment: that's right. I added this into the constraints. see the image attached to the question

Comment: I guess the problem is infeasible. Note that `x(i)*p(i)>=P'` means `P'>0 => x(i)=1`. As `P`=0.6` you force all `x(i)=1`. This will make `sum(i, p(i)*x(i))<=5` infeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the set of constraints that you currently have, *when combined* are infeasible.
If you relax them a little, Excel will find the optimal solution.

First, look at `pi * xi > 0.6 for all i` 
This does two things. Since all pi is greater than 0, all the xi variables are forced to be 1. (0 is not possible)

Also, look at the last column, xi. Since that pi is 0.2, even for x=1, `xi * pi` cannot be >0.6. (To find a feasible solution, you have to lower your P' to be 0.2

2. Now look at your other constraint:
   `sum of pi * xi < 5`

All your pi's add up to 5.4. And due to the previous set of constraints, all the X's are forced to take on the value of 1. So you have to make B10 to be at least 5.4.

All that said, I suspect that you don't want your xi to be binary. Perhaps, you want them to be `0 <= xi <= 1,` that is, they can take fractional values as well.

After relaxing the values of B10 and B16, Excel was able to find a solution. See image below.

[image]

**Update Based on OP's Clarification**

1. Your Xi variables are fine. 0 means taxi is running, 1 means it will go for repair.
2. Objective function: Minimize cost of repair (Sumproduct of Ci Xi) is also fine.
3. You have to change the Individual taxi constraint. As the problem defines it, pi = 0 is good, pi of 1 is bad. The company doesn't want ANY taxi to have its pi more than a threshold P'.

   Constraint:  `pi * (1-Xi) <= 0.6` (say)

   Think about this: As soon as any taxi's pi crosses the threshold, it will be forced to go for repair since Xi will have to become 1.
4. The global availability: For this, you can simply sum up the 'available taxis' and make sure that there are more than the required minimum (say 5)

   `sum(1-xi) >=5`

If you set up your Excel model this way, you will get a feasible solution.

See Image below:

[image]

**Update 2: Including a Global Degradation Index cap**

If instead of constraint 4. above, you wanted a constraint that kept the sum of all pi's under some limit you would do the following:

`(1-xi)` is the indicator for a taxi in service.

So this constraint becomes:

`Sum of pi * (1-xi) <= P'`

For convenience, you can create a row in Excel which is (1-xi) and then use Sumproduct of that row and the pi row.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my formulation, a vehicle is available if it is not in repair. To me, pi is a degradation index. High pi means it needs to get repaired soon. For day to day availability, I simply add up the number in service at a given time T. That is what my constraint 4 does.

Comment: Got it. I've updated my response to include the global degradation constraint.